# start login screen from base class when application is resumed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

In my application I want the Login Activity to start if there is no internet connection when the application is resumed. In my Base Class I have used intent to start the login activity. But the application gets stuck and does not resume properly. I have almost 25 activities that  extends the base Activity.
This is the code I have used in the `onResume` of Base Activity.

```
    public void onResume(){

    String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(this);

    if(status!=null && status.equals("Not connected to Internet"))
    {
    Intent i=new Intent(this, LoginActivity.this);
    startActivity(i);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Curly Braces after `if()` Likes this...

```
public void onResume(){

       ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
            =(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();


    if(activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected())
    {
    Intent i=new Intent(this, LoginActivity.this);
    startActivity(i);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have edited my post. This does not solve the problem

Comment: I have edited the code..try this to check internet Connectivty... @nullvoid

Comment: there is no problem with the internet. I have checked the status variable and it gives correct state of the internet connection. The problem is in calling the intent in the onResume. For some reason the intent does not work properly. The intent does start but the application slows down and gets stuck.The reason I guess is that I am using the intent in the onResume of Base Activity but I cannot think of any other solution.

Comment: Calling `startActivity()` in `onResume()` is absolutely fine. 

All `startActivity()` does is tell Android to start the new activity and add it to the top of the back stack when the main thread becomes available, which in this instance will be after Android has finished calling all the necessary lifecycle callbacks on the current activity.

If you are experiencing odd behaviour I doubt is related to this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add curly braces to you if statement. Right now it's only sometimes making the intent, but always trying to start it.

```
public void onResume(){ 

    String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(this);

    if(status!=null && status.equals("Not connected to Internet")) {

        Intent i=new Intent(this, LoginActivity.this);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my post. This does not solve the problem